# Is cursor feedback gone for good?

Tags: 11.10, cursor

Back in 11.04 and before, whenever I clicked on an app icon, I would get the spinning wheel if the app didn't load immediately. In 11.10, after clicking on an app from the launcher, there's no feedback which tells me that I have clicked on the icon.  Mac OS X, for example, handles this by bouncing the icon, so that you know the app is launching.

Is cursor feedback a thing of the past in 11.10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Feedback still exists: if you click an icon of an unopened app on the launcher, you should see it pulsing until the app is open.  It will also wiggle if it wants your attention but does not have focus.

Comment: I don't seem to see that effect.  Where can I check if this has been set from compiz?

Comment: This should happen by default with Unity.  I don't know if this is the case with Ubuntu-2D.